# Why must you restart Ruby on Rails after installing plugins?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, rubygems

Why is it that after installing certain plugins I have to restart the rails development server even though I can change my code and have it update the server without restarting? What is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're installing new gems, you will need to restart the server for Rails to pick them up, because their load paths are configured in `boot.rb` which is processed on application start:

```
# Set up gems listed in the Gemfile.
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../../Gemfile', __FILE__)
require 'bundler/setup' if File.exist?(ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'])
```

> In a standard Rails application, there's a Gemfile which declares all dependencies of the application. config/boot.rb sets ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] to the location of this file. If the Gemfile exists, then bundler/setup is required. The require is used by Bundler to configure the load path for your Gemfile's dependencies.

(from [the reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html#config-boot-rb))

If the load paths aren't set, Rails doesn't know where to load your gems from.

By default, on every request all your application code is reloaded, thus you can see your updates.

If you have a plugin/gem installed and are changing it (say, you're developing one), the plugins and their code aren't reloaded, so you need to manually restart the Rails server so the updates are picked up.

This behaviour set by the `config.reload_plugins` configuration variable, which defaults to `false` for better performance, since usually you change your application code and the plugins are unchanged. If you set it to `true` (in `development.rb`, since it's only necessary in the dev environment), Rails should reload all installed plugin code on every request. Of course, every request will then take longer because more code needs to be reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you only restart the server when you code tinkers with the server such as through redirecting, or sessions expiration or database switching or anything along those lines. If your plugins affect the server then you have to restart to fully implement the plugin. It may just be that the particular plugin that you installed may not have affected the server.